# Undefined reference to 'xdr_int'

Tags: rcp

I was doing an assignment in rpc. When i run the command "make -f Makefile.add" it throws me the following errors:

```
cc -g     -o add_client  add_clnt.o add_client.o add_xdr.o -lnsl 
/usr/bin/ld: add_clnt.o: in function `add_1':
/home/mridu/rpc/add_clnt.c:18: undefined reference to `xdr_int'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mridu/rpc/add_clnt.c:18: undefined reference to `xdr_int'
/usr/bin/ld: add_client.o: in function `add_prog_1':
/home/mridu/rpc/add_client.c:18: undefined reference to `clnt_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mridu/rpc/add_client.c:20: undefined reference to `clnt_pcreateerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mridu/rpc/add_client.c:27: undefined reference to `clnt_perror'
/usr/bin/ld: add_xdr.o: in function `xdr_numbers':
/home/mridu/rpc/add_xdr.c:13: undefined reference to `xdr_int'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/mridu/rpc/add_xdr.c:15: undefined reference to `xdr_int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.add:41: add_client] Error 1
```

The following code is the code in the Makefile.add:

```
# This is a template Makefile generated by rpcgen

# Parameters

CLIENT = add_client
SERVER = add_server

SOURCES_CLNT.c =
SOURCES_CLNT.h =
SOURCES_SVC.c =
SOURCES_SVC.h =
SOURCES.x = add.x

TARGETS_SVC.c = add_svc.c add_server.c add_xdr.c
TARGETS_CLNT.c = add_clnt.c add_client.c add_xdr.c
TARGETS = add.h add_xdr.c add_clnt.c add_svc.c add_client.c add_server.c

OBJECTS_CLNT = $(SOURCES_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c:%.c=%.o)
OBJECTS_SVC = $(SOURCES_SVC.c:%.c=%.o) $(TARGETS_SVC.c:%.c=%.o)
# Compiler flags 

CFLAGS += -g
LDLIBS += -lnsl
LIBS+= -ltirrp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -ltirpc
RPCGENFLAGS =

# Targets 

all : $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)

$(TARGETS) : $(SOURCES.x)
        rpcgen $(RPCGENFLAGS) $(SOURCES.x)

$(OBJECTS_CLNT) : $(SOURCES_CLNT.c) $(SOURCES_CLNT.h) $(TARGETS_CLNT.c)

$(OBJECTS_SVC) : $(SOURCES_SVC.c) $(SOURCES_SVC.h) $(TARGETS_SVC.c)

$(CLIENT) : $(OBJECTS_CLNT) 
        $(LINK.c) -o $(CLIENT) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(LDLIBS) 

$(SERVER) : $(OBJECTS_SVC)
        $(LINK.c) -o $(SERVER) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(LDLIBS)

 clean:
        $(RM) core $(TARGETS) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

The following is the code from the add.x file:

```
struct numbers{
        int num1;
        int num2;
};

program ADD_PROG{
        version ADD_VER{
                int ADD( numbers )=1;
        }=1;
}=0x23456789;
```

I tried adding the compiler flags:

```
LIBS+= -ltirrp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -ltirpc
```

But it still doesn't work. Help me solve the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late, you probably solved it already, but, I think you should change the `LIBS` to:

```
LIBS += -ltirpc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Makefile-

```
LIBS += -ltirpc
```

Also update these lines-

```
$(CLIENT) : $(OBJECTS_CLNT) 
    $(LINK.c) -o $(CLIENT) $(OBJECTS_CLNT) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)

$(SERVER) : $(OBJECTS_SVC) 
    $(LINK.c) -o $(SERVER) $(OBJECTS_SVC) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

For using the TI-RPC you need to make the following changes in the Makefile.add:

```
CFLAGS += -g -I/usr/include/tirpc
LDLIBS += -lnsl -ltirpc
```

1. Give proper path in `CFLAGS` of TI-RPC libraries, in my case it is
   `/usr/include/tirpc`.
2. Test by using the commnad `make -f Makefile.add`.

Make sure you have required permissions to make changes and execute.